# how to get checkbox value in dropdown select box menu

Tags: php, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I am working on a project and puzzle by a issue, there i have to send some check box value and then get them in a dropdown list, for example my checkbox form is:

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="rain" />rain</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="climate" />climate</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="qual[]" value="awesome" />awesome</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="send" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

now i am trying to retrieve this on next page in dropdownlist as:

```
<?php
$check=$_POST['qual'];
foreach($check as $val)
{
echo '<select>
  <option value="volvo">'.$val.'`</option>

</select>';
}

?>
```

but i am getting all check box value in one option value of select box,
so any idea about how to sort out this, if something is missing or my question is not clear then let me know....
thanx in advance....

Comment: Should be `<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'`</option>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$check=$_POST['qual'];
echo '<select>';
foreach($check as $val)
{

echo'<option value=\"volvo\">'.$val.'`</option>


}
echo '</select>'
?>
```